# How to solve the error N: Ignoring file 'sources.list.tmp' in direct........?

Tags: system-installation

```
N: Ignoring file 'sources.list.tmp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'rm' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'sudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/   
sudo rm sources.list.tmp sudo rm   
sudo update
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that don't stick to the rules for source list files. `apt` informs you that it just ignores thoses files:

```
Ignoring file 'sources.list.tmp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

There seems to be a file `sources.list.tmp` (maybe a temporary file from a text editor?). Source list files need to have the ending `.list`. But I'd assume that this file is left there accidentally, anyway.

The situtation is similar for the other two notices:

```
Ignoring file 'rm' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension

Ignoring file 'sudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

There seem to be files named `rm` and `sudo`, respectively, that also don't follow the naming rules for source list files.

The following might seem a bit condescending, but it's in general a good idea to actually *read* the error messages ;) Very often they literarily spell out where to look to solve the problem.